# How to detect file is open with silverlight saveDialog for C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, savefiledialog

If a file is open by another application, and then I try to save it through the Silverlight SaveDialog, I can catch the error with an exception but after that I get this error.

Line: 57
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation can only occur on the UI Thread.
   at System.Windows.Hosting.NativeHost.VerifyThread()
   at System.Windows.SaveFileStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Finalize()

**I would prefer to detect that the file is open, but can't seem to do that.  I tried fs.CanWrite, but it returns true, even when the file is open by another application.**

EDIT: [Here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/176869.aspx/1/10?Problem%20disposing%20SaveFileStream%20with%20SaveFileDialog%20when%20error%20opening%20file%20) is a post on the silverlight forum that seems to explain what is happening, although they think it's just Office files.  I'm having the problem with a PDF file.

Here is my code:

```
    public void PDFSaveFile(bool success)
    {
        // silverlight requires saveFileDialog to be user-initiated, 
        // so this is called from the OK button of a pop-up window
        // ignore success, we only gave an OK option
        byte[] fileBytes = doc.ToPDF().ToArray();
        PDFClose();

        try
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDlg.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            bool? dialogResult = saveFileDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dialogResult == true)
            {
                using (var fs = saveFileDlg.OpenFile())
                {
                    fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.HandleInternalError(string.Format("Unable to save file: {0}",ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use
FileInfo.Open
if return a IOException = File already opened

[FileInfo.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya63c7c5.aspx)